# Visual studio extension development - viewing files like peek window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, preview

I am developing a Visual Studio 2017 extension. I already have a list of files with line numbers.

Requirements:

- On a specific command, in an opened file in the IDE, in a specific line, I want to open all the files and navigate to the line numbers.
- The view should be same as the peek definition window shown below. Show all the file list on the right and the code on the left.
- On clicking the filename, the code should open on the left to the correct line number.

How can I achieve this?

Sample image:
[image: Sample image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you do have any research about this issue?